# The right approach for business logic in my windows form application in C#

Tags: c#

I am a student and developing a simple assignment - windows form application in visual studio 2010.

The application is suppose to construct formulas as per user requirement.

The process: It has to pick data from columns of Microsoft Access database and the user should be able to pick the data by column name like we do in a drop down menu. and create reusable formulas in it ( configure it once and can change it again). followings are column titles from database that can be picked for example.

e.g

> ```
>   Col -1  : Marks in Maths
>   Col -2  : Total Marks in Maths
>   Col -3  : Marks in science
>   Col -4  : Total marks in science
> ```

Finally we should be able to construct any formula in the UI like

> (Col 1 + Col 3 ) / ( col 2 + col 4) =  Formula 1

once this is set and a name is assigned to it by user.

He would be able to calculate his desired figures by only  manipulating underlying data on the UI layer....

Problem:

It looks like I have to create an app where rules are set through UI....... this means no stored procedures are required.... please suggest the right approach.

Comment: Have you done the first step? Bring back data from the Access DB?

Comment: well i imported the data into the data grid..it brings the entire column data.

Comment: This seems like it might be a question better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: This site isn't really meant for designing specific apps for users. I understand the frustration of not knowing where to start, but this just isn't the forum for it.